# R programming language: meaning of 'weights' parameter in library method 'loess'

Tags: r, loess, nonparametric-regression

I use the library method loess of the R programming language for non parametric data fitting. The dataset is two-dimensional. I have not found any proper documentation of the method parameter `weights`.

My data points are normally distributed random variables, and I also have an estimate of their respective standard deviations. I am wondering whether the parameter `weights` allows me to supply R with the details of the standard deviations. In other words: I wonder whether the individual weights in `weights` are (relative) measures of data quality, so that the fit can be improved if some measure of data uncertainty is supplied via the parameter weights.

I further suspect the entries in `weights` are used as additional weights in the weighted least squares regressions of local datasets in the LOESS procedure (maybe as additional weight prefactors for the (position dependent) kernel functions?). This would suggest that for the case of data points which are independent normally distributed random variables, but which still have different noise levels (i.e. different standard deviations as in my case, since the data points come from different and independent series of measurements), the weights should be chosen as `1/\sigma_{i}^2`, where `\sigma_{i}` is the standard deviation of the respective random variable/data point. If someone knows for sure, that would be nice to know.

Answer (score 1):

This page confirms my suspicion:

https://docs.tibco.com/pub/enterprise-runtime-for-R/3.1.0/doc/html/Language_Reference/stats/loess.html

Regarding the parameter `weights` of `loess` it says:

> an optional expression for weights to give to **individual observations
>   in the sum of squared residuals that forms the local fitting
>   criterion**. By default, an unweighted fit is carried out. If it is
>   supplied, weights is treated as an expression to evaluate in the same
>   data frame as the model formula. It should evaluate to a non-negative
>   numeric vector. **If the different observations have nonequal variances,
>   weights should be inversely proportional to the variances**.